# Transpose ID, Field 'Name' Field 'Value' records from rows to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, pivot

Before this question gets closed as a duplicate, I have seen many, many examples of 'SQL Dynamic Pivot Tables' on SO, but nothing I have tried so far has worked.  Many of the examples that use a PIVOT expect a SUM or MAX value.  I don't have any of these.

I have a single table SQL Server database.

The table holds products and associated properties.  You could argue the properties should be split into a separate table, but I am stuck with what I have.. 1 table.

**Example table (tblObject):**

| prodId | fieldName | fieldValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | name | widget1 |
| ABC123 | description | Great widget! |
| ABC123 | status | reserved |
|  |  |  |
| XYZ999 | name | widget9 |
| XYZ999 | description | Lovely widget! |
| XYZ999 | status | active |

Each ProdId can have many fieldNames. My example table just shows name, description and status, but it could for expand to include colour, style, serial number etc. etc.

I need to report each prodId with all of the fieldName and fieldValue transposed, as below.

**Desired Output:**

| prodId | prodName | name | description | status | createdDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | widget1 | widget1 | Great widget! | reserved | 2022-10-27 |
| XYZ999 | widget9 | widget9 | Lovely widget! | active | 2022-10-27 |

I thought this would be extremely simple, but it is causing me quite a headache!

My current approach is below, but sadly is not functioning:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT prodId, fieldName, fieldValue
  FROM tblObjects
) Results
PIVOT (
  fieldValue
  FOR fieldName
  IN (SELECT fieldName from tblObjects GROUP BY fieldName)
  )
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: What would your output look like with some products having 1 FieldName and other products having 20 fieldNames?

Comment: Good question, I should have elaborated in my post.  There are some fieldNames (name, description, status) that are applicable to all objects and they will be shown on my main form.  I will probably only run the transpose query per ProdId (e.g. `WHERE prodId = 'ABC123'`) and therefore, all fields will be applicable.

Comment: That then contradicts with your desired results above; you would however have to use the Prodid key to retrieve and dynamically build a pivot query based on the relevant columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not quite understanding how the aggregate functions affect the pivot values. They should only be grouped by the other values (in your case prodID).

Let's mock the data up:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #table;
CREATE TABLE #table (prodID NVARCHAR(6), fieldName NVARCHAR(20), fieldValue NVARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO #table (prodId, fieldName, fieldValue) VALUES
('ABC123', 'name'           , 'widget1'),
('ABC123', 'description'    , 'Great widget!'),
('ABC123', 'status'         , 'reserved'),
('XYZ999', 'name'           , 'widget9'),
('XYZ999', 'description'    , 'Lovely widget!'),
('XYZ999', 'status'         , 'active');
```

I used a temp table here because table variables are harder to work with when it comes to dSQL.

Before we can do the pivot we need two things, the list of values from the column, and the SQL itself:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX), @dpvt NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @dpvt = STRING_AGG(fieldName,',')
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT fieldName FROM #table) a;

SET @cmd = '
SELECT prodID, name AS prodName, '+@dpvt+', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS createdDate
  FROM #table t
    PIVOT (
           MAX(fieldValue) FOR fieldName IN ('+@dpvt+')
          ) p;';
```

With those sorted out we can execute sp_executeSQL and perform our dynamic pivot:

```
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd;
```

```
prodID  prodName    name    description     status      createdDate
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC123  widget1     widget1 Great widget!   reserved    2022-11-01 15:34:36.430
XYZ999  widget9     widget9 Lovely widget!  active      2022-11-01 15:34:36.430
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.. is there a way to remove the hardcoding of the fieldName values (name, description, status) in your query?  They are not fixed and therefore cannot be hardcoded... Thanks..

Comment: Ha, I had intended to remove those, I'll update the answer.
the first one needs to stay to get your requested outcome (the prodName column is just a duplicate of 'name').

Comment: Patrick, did you try your query?  I cannot get it to run.. I get errors.. once I have fixed conflicting names, it runs, but just returns a single column of 'prodID'.

Comment: Yep, it runs and produces the data I included in the answer. What errors did you get? What changes did you make?

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I got it working, upvoted and accepted.  Appreciate you taking the time to answer :)